# Python : simple code gives "generator object", why?

Tags: python

I m trying to learn to code in a "pythonic way".

The original code is working, results and displays the expected results.
The new code is giving: "<generator object  at 0x0000017862039510>". Why then ?

Original code:

```
a={
    'AA':-5,
    'BB':-8,
    'C':15,
    'D':-85,
    'E':24
}

for i in a.values():
    if i<0:
        print(i)
```

New code :

```
a={
    'AA':-5,
    'BB':-8,
    'C':15,
    'D':-85,
    'E':24
}
        
print(i for i in a.values() if i<0 )
```

Thank you !

Comment: Because the code you wrote between the parentheses is a generator expression: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/.

Comment: Thank you both !

Comment: Why do you think it should give anything else? Where did you learn this syntax, and what did it tell you about how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i for i in a.values() if i<0` is a generator - it doesn't resolve to a sequence of values unless something iterates it. For parsing reasons, you can't have the generator by itself without enclosing it in grouping parenthesis

```
>>> i for i in a.values() if i<0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    i for i in a.values() if i<0
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> (i for i in a.values() if i<0)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f2a54b3ac80>
```

`print` just takes the string representation of objects. It doesn't try to iterate them. So, you get the string representation of the generator itself. Other objects are different - lists and tuples for instance, *do* iterate their initialization value.

```
>>> list(i for i in a.values() if i<0)
[-5, -8, -85]
>>> tuple(i for i in a.values() if i<0)
(-5, -8, -85)
```

List comprehensions do the same thing - build lists using the same generator semantics

```
>>> [i for i in a.values() if i<0]
[-5, -8, -85]
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was exactly looking for this solution with list: ist(i for i in a.values() if i<0) !

Answer (score 0):

To print out the values of the generator, separated by a newline, you can use `.join` method which will create a string by joining each element of the generator with a newline (note that the values in the generator must be strings (in this case they need to be explicitly converted)):

```py
print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in a.values() if i < 0))
```

Comment: Or `print(*(i for i in a.values() if i < 0), sep="\n")`

Comment: Would a list comprehension also be a good choice? This is what I tend to do since it seems cleaner/simpler: [print(i) for i in a.values() if i<0]

Comment: @Mandias there is no point for that, it just creates a list with a bunch of None elements, granted it will also execute the print functions and print `i`, but that is not how list comprehensions are supposed to be used, then just stick to the regular `for loop`

Comment: @Mandias That works, but the list can get unnecessarily large (and thus make it slow) if the number of values is large for a simple operation of printing every item in a list. After printing, python discards a large number of (None) values you didn't need to create in the first place.

Comment: @AlanBagel to the first comment: yeah, that is also possible, however, I have a feeling that it is slightly slower; to the second comment: also that list will probably get garbage collected immediately so I wouldn't worry that much about space if using it that way (tho it will temporarily take a lot of it), more of that it just isn't the supposed use and also it would be slower because of multiple `print`

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Thank you for the response and all the comments, I learned a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The expression which is written in that print statement of yours is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). In your original code, you iterate through each key-value pair in your dictionary and print the value. In your new code, you are attempting to print the result of that expression which is an object and not a series of print statements.

Comment: Thank you very much !